# How to include semantic-ui fonts using bower and ember-cli

Tags: css, ember.js, fonts, bower, semantic-ui

I want to use semantic-ui within ember-cli project, having trouble with including fonts.

`bower install semantic-ui`

Import css and fonts in `Brocfile.js`

```
app.import('bower_components/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.css');
app.import('bower_components/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.js');

var semanticFonts = 
    pickFiles('bower_components/semantic-ui/dist/themes/default/assets/fonts', {
      srcDir: '/',
      files: ['**/*'],
      destDir: 'assets/themes/default/assets/fonts'
});
```

This works, because `semantic.css` looks for `themes/default/assets/fonts` relative to itself.

Note the `destDir: 'assets/themes/default/assets/fonts'`, this is because ember-cli puts the `semantic-css` within `assets/` folder, and I have to put the fonts in that folder. But this looks like a hack is there a better solution?

Finally `semantic-ui` dist folder doesn't include different build options, do I have to compile the project myself eg: using gulp?, I thought using bower it should be straightforward.

Comment: Would you mind editing and posting your full Brocfile? Simply adding that pickFiles piece did not work for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We also got 404's for the fonts after installing Semantic via Bower. We solved it by adding the font folder as a tree to the Ember build.var

```
EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
var pickFiles = require('broccoli-static-compiler');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    babel: {
      includePolyfill: true
    },
    fingerprint: {
      extensions: ['js', 'css', /*'png', 'jpg', 'gif',*/ 'map']
    }
  });

  app.import('bower_components/semantic/dist/semantic.css');
  app.import('vendor/shims.js');

  var semanticIcons = pickFiles('bower_components/semantic/dist/themes/default/assets/fonts', {
    srcDir: '/',
    destDir: '/assets/themes/default/assets/fonts'
  });

  return app.toTree([semanticIcons]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at semantic-ui, it seems pretty gigantic, and specifically setup with gulp.

First off, I would use the flag `--save` in your bower request.

`bower install --save semantic-ui`

This will add it as a dependency to your bower.json automatically - or `--save-dev` if it's only for development and not production.

Semantic-ui looks like it's written in "LESS", so not only do you have to deal with a favored build tool, but also it has opinions about the preprocessor.

The fonts involved seem to be just some google includes, and some svg fonts.

My advice, *if you really really want to use a monstrous set of CSS declarations like this*, - in this situation -   *would be* to take the /dist output .css and .js -and- combine it with YOUR favorite css pre processing setup - and just override where appropriate. - or borrow the forms *or whatever specific styles lead you to want to use this.*

I am worried that fully integrating it into your ember project wont be as smooth as intended... and that you won't get a terribly useful amount of stuff out of keeping it in sync.

Just my opinion, - but I can't comment yet. - and I think you would be better off just writing the styles in stylus from scratch anyways. : )

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I don't know if there's a better way, but I added the following line to the `config/application.rb`

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components', 'semantic-ui', 'dist')
```

This adds the dist folder to the asset path, so when semantic-ui is looking for /themes, it will be picked up.